# Using Regex to extract multi-line SAS code

Tags: python, regex, sas, multiline

I am trying using Python to go through many thousands of lines of SAS code. I want to extract certain parts of the code to be printed or to be sent to another function.

The SAS code I am looking at might look like this:

```
"""%macro msg (name= some_macro) ;
%put Hello World, my name is &name ;
 %mend ;"""
```

And I want to capture what it between the first and the last line, i.e. between the `%macro` and the `%mend ;` line,so "%put Hello World, my name is &name ;" would be returned as a group.

I can achieve this capture with:

```
re.compile(r"\%macro\s*?.*?\s*?\((.*)\)\s*?;\n(.*?)\n\s*\%mend\s*;")
```

As `(.*?)\n` seems to match the line I want.

NOTE: I am using a lot of `\s*` because I see whitespace all over the SAS code which seems to be pretty random.

However when the SAS code is over more lines (it could be 2 or many more), I do not have the ability to pattern match, so for example,

```
"""%macro msg (name= some_macro) ;
%put Hello World, my name is &name ;
%let something happen
%do something else
%mend ;"""
```

Here I want to return "%put Hello World, my name is &name ; %let something happen %do something else" all as one group. I have tried putting in quantifiers, `*` and `+` but I do not know how to make it clear that want to check for the whole line repeating, rather than just the last character I put the quantifier next to. I will give this as an example:

```
r"\%macro\s*?.*?\s*?\((.*)\)\s*?;\n(.*?)\n+?\s*\%mend\s*;"
```

Here I am trying to indicate the line `(.*?)\n` could be repeated between 1 and unlimited times, and that I want to capture that group.

I have also tried to use `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL`, using ^ and $ and dots for line end charters, but didn't achieve the desired result either.

Please help me understand this area better. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to capture the body of the macro definition?  Do you really want to skip the macro name?  Do you really want to skip the parameter definition, the part in the parentheses after the macro name?  Note that the parameter list, including the parentheses, is optional. The `%mend` statement does not need to be at the start of a line.  But it does need a trailing semi-colon to send the statement.

Comment: Yes, in this case I am trying to capture the body of the macro definition. I will have some regex to capture the macro name too. I want to go through and capture all comments, macro definitions, proc and data steps. This is really hard though because there are complicating factors such as comments within data steps, and nested data and proc steps within macros. I am trying to create an interpreter of SAS code which prints out some English about what's happening in each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single capture group and match the lines that do not start with %mend.

The percentage sign does not need escaping and note that `\s` could also match a newline if that is not intended.

```
%macro.*\r?\n((?:(?!\s*%mend).*\r?\n)+)\s*%mend ;
```

**Explanation**

- `%macro.*\r?\n` Match %macro followed by the rest of the line and a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!\s*%mend)` Negative lookahead, if what is on the right is not `%mend`
    - `.*\r?\n` Match the whole line and a newline
  - `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times to match at least a single line
- `)` Close capture group 1
- `\s*%mend ;`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rio03o/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JXPzpD)

For example

```
pattern = re.compile(r"%macro.*\r?\n((?:(?!\s*%mend).*\r?\n)+)\s*%mend ;")
print(re.findall(pattern, test_str))
```